# News API for use in application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, feed

I want to include the latest news as part of my application, does anybody know any news APIs or sites where they say you can use their news for your app?

Answer (score 6):

Use [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS).  You can choose feeds from wherever you want, they're widely available.  (Just make sure the content owners are okay with it if you are only reading specific feeds.)  It's in XML, so there are plenty of libraries for reading that.  In fact an RSS reader is typically one of the types of things (next to twitter clients) used to teach iPhone programming, so a little googling will find you lots of sample code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plenty of RSS reader samples on the internet, for Mac OS X or iPhone. You can use custom XML parser or JSON. Check github for samples.

Answer (score 1):

Financial News only:

MyAllies Companies Breaking News with JSON output

Example:

http://app.myallies.com/api/news for all companies recent news.

Or

http://app.myallies.com/api/news/amzn for Amazon news.

Free service, no limit (at least for now)

Answer (score 0):

Why not considering a news search API? Newsriver (https://newsriver.io) mines hundreds of thousand online sources and aggregates their news articles. It's API allows to retrieve structured online news articles via simple search queries.

Comment: I keep constantly getting 504 codes with them. The request url and authorization are correct (copied from their website). What could be the reason? What's the simplest search/source I can run without 504? Just want to test them out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you or anyone else is still looking for a news API but you could get curated financial and business news with relevant financial asset and other tags from here - http://www.cityfalcon.com/financial-news-api.  You could also get financial tweets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want stock news specifically I suggest IEX, Alphavantage or [stocknewsapi](https://www.stocknewsapi.com) I personally use stock news api as it is the most relevant and the images are great quality. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Both ContextualWeb's [News API](https://contextualweb.io/news-api/) and [newsapi.org](http://newsapi.org) offer very generous free tiers (10,000 requests/month on ContextualWeb and 500 requests/day on newsapi.org), and both are very easy to embed in your app or website. You can easily filter by news outlet or topic. ContextualWeb also uses Natural Language Processing to extract the topics from each article, which might make results easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I used [datanews.io](https://datanews.io). Its REST API worked well in my case.

It also can monitor different news queries - be sure to check that out as well.